# Change text style for specific words within CSS Content

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

To cut down on having a div for every different part of bold text etc is it possible to target specific parts within CSS content to be bold etc. Can I use spans any way at all? I've figured out how to do newline stuff so thats one big help that will enable me to have to create a div for every single paragraph too.

For example

```
<span class="maintext">Blah blah blah <br>etc | etc <br> <strong>something in bold.</strong> more text here.</span>
```

Would require three divs adding to address the CSS content, one of the content up to the bold string, one for the bold string and one for the content after the bold string.

If I could somehow add the bold line within one CSS Content selector that would be ideal.

Comment: Give an example of the HTML you want change

Comment: Added a rough example

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith hmm maybe yes - is there a way in simple Javascript to do something like "if this exact string is matched, make bold?" that way I could enter the raw content and as javascript sees the part of the content which matches a specific sentence it would bold it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the simplest javascript I could come up with: https://jsfiddle.net/vctbszc2/1/

HTML

```
<p>
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah DEMO blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
</p>
```

Javascript

```
var par = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(var i = 0; i < par.length; i++)
{
    var s = par[i].innerHTML;
    s = s.replace('DEMO', '<span style="color:green; font-size: 40px;">DEMO</span>');
    par[i].innerHTML = s;
}
```

Comment: Ah nope, its blocked - makes sense in theory you could change the eBay page content couldn't you.

For the record they say...
"Your listing cannot contain javascript (".cookie", "cookie(", "replace(", IFRAME, META, or includes), cookies or base href."

Comment: I am going to have to say its not possible then.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Nevermind, its do able just with a lot more CSS - thought at least you can do plain text and bold in one div with before and after locators. Granted this is a hell of a bizarre way of entering content but it could also be the perfect solution to a horrible system.

Answer (score 0):

You could use content as shown below. But there is no chance eBay will let you get away with that.

```
p:after {
content: "Add text here";
}
```

Comment: Yeah i've already figured that out (and there's no reason they wont let you use it, its part of an external style sheet) - what I want to do is format the text so I don't have to create a new div just to put bolt text in the middle of a sentence for instance.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith thats exactly what i'm asking - is there a hacky way to get spans in there, you can't do it by default, but maybe i'm missing a way to use quotes that I might be able to achieve it. Probably not, but worth asking.

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith nope - can't embed javascript on eBay. It's very very limiting. Pure CSS only - limited Javascript works but to be honest i've had no luck with it. CSS3 stuff is fine though, although its very very very picky about formatting, much more so than browsers.

Comment: So your answer will be no, not possible.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith whats your javascript idea? There is very limited support for (not external javascripts for instance) but if its something simple I could possibly give it a shot.

Comment: No promises, but this ,might work for you see my answer.

Comment: CSS content cant add tags to the page (tags are structural) - CSS is meant for presentation changes, not structural.

Javascript or jQuery would do it, but again eBay will be stripping down your code to prevent this. jQuery would look like:

$("div.DivName").after("your HTML here");